# How to use google Sheet as an database

Tags: google-apps-script

How to generate the google sheet data in HTML web app and it should allow users to update the comments from HTML web app...?

I have some data in google sheet (Submitted through google form) I want to search the sheet data from web app based on "Request Number" using search button  + should able to update the comments from web apps and that should get reflected in google sheet (On the same cell )

[Google Sheet-File](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jrq4fgQdk1ccHGRD3cEY4EQsx5FvXRJuZp-9smOEVsw/edit#gid=0)

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('index')
      .evaluate();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS5i2zvZQw0qJxPbgHrCp3tu_L0RjzTvBZBr5xROg7AVE0E4kR9" alt="IIFL LOGO" style="width:100px;height:50px;">
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Requset Number">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3"><label for="usr"><p class="text-primary">Requset Number</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr"></div>
     <div class="col-xs-3"><label for="usr"><p class="text-primary">Assgined To</label><select class="form-control" id="sel1">
     <option>User1</option>
    <option>User2</option>
    <option>User3</option>
    <option>User4</option>
    </select>
  </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"><label for="usr"><p class="text-primary">Request Status</label><select class="form-control" id="sel1">
    <option>New</option>
    <option>Open</option>
    <option>Hold</option>
    <option>Reject</option>
    <option>Quote - In Process</option>
    <option>Negotiation – In process</option>
    <option>Commercial Closed</option>
    <option>PRS in Process</option>
    <option>PO in Process</option>
    <option>PO Send to Vendor</option>
    <option>Negotiation – In process</option>
    <option>Delivered</option>
    <option>Paid</option>
    <option>Closed</option>
  </select>
  </div>
</div>
 <hr style="height:2px;border-width:0;color:gray;background-color:gray">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3"><label for="usr"><p class="text-primary">Timestamp</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"><label for="usr"><p class="text-primary">Business User</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"><label for="usr"><p class="text-primary">Request Type</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"><label for="usr"><p class="text-primary">Request For</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr"></div>
</div>
 <hr style="height:2px;border-width:0;color:gray;background-color:gray">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"><label for="usr">Short Description</label><textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="comment"></textarea></div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"><label for="usr">Remark Note</label><textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="comment"></textarea></div>
</div>
 <hr style="height:2px;border-width:0;color:gray;background-color:gray">
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" class="center">Clik here to Update/Save the Comments </button>    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried with google sheets api ? https://developers.google.com/sheets/

Comment: Yes,  I am able to submit the new data but not able to retrieve the existing data and also not able to update, May required some sample script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer the below code to search & update a request. Also I have fixed the bootstrap classes.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS5i2zvZQw0qJxPbgHrCp3tu_L0RjzTvBZBr5xROg7AVE0E4kR9" alt="IIFL LOGO" style="width:100px;height:50px;">
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" onsubmit="return searchRequest();">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="requestID" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Requset Number">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3"><label for="usr"><p class="text-primary">Requset Number</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="requestNumber"></div>
     <div class="col-xs-3"><label for="usr"><p class="text-primary">Assgined To</label><select class="form-control" id="assignedTo">
     <option>User1</option>
    <option>User2</option>
    <option>User3</option>
    <option>User4</option>
    </select>
  </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"><label for="usr"><p class="text-primary">Request Status</label><select class="form-control" id="status">
    <option>New</option>
    <option>Open</option>
    <option>Hold</option>
    <option>Reject</option>
    <option>Quote - In Process</option>
    <option>Negotiation – In process</option>
    <option>Commercial Closed</option>
    <option>PRS in Process</option>
    <option>PO in Process</option>
    <option>PO Send to Vendor</option>
    <option>Negotiation – In process</option>
    <option>Delivered</option>
    <option>Paid</option>
    <option>Closed</option>
  </select>
  </div>
</div>
 <hr style="height:2px;border-width:0;color:gray;background-color:gray">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3"><label for="usr"><p class="text-primary">Timestamp</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="timestamp"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"><label for="usr"><p class="text-primary">Business User</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="BU"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"><label for="usr"><p class="text-primary">Request Type</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="rTpe"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"><label for="usr"><p class="text-primary">Request For</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="rFor"></div>
</div>
 <hr style="height:2px;border-width:0;color:gray;background-color:gray">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"><label for="usr">Short Description</label><textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="shortDesc"></textarea></div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"><label for="usr">Remark Note</label><textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="remark"></textarea></div>
</div>
 <hr style="height:2px;border-width:0;color:gray;background-color:gray">
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="updateRequest()" id="updateBtn" class="center">Clik here to Update/Save the Comments </button>    
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
function searchRequest(){
  if($("#requestID").val()!=""){
    $("form input,form button").attr("disabled",true);
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(displayData).fetchRequestDetails($("#requestID").val())
  };
  return false;
}

function displayData(result){
  $("form input,form button").attr("disabled",false);
  if(result!= -1){
    console.log(result)
    $("#updateBtn").attr("disabled",false);
    $("#requestNumber").val(result[0][0]);
    $("#assignedTo").val(result[0][6]);
    $("#status").val(result[0][7]);
    $("#timestamp").val(result[0][1]);
    $("#BU").val(result[0][2]);
    $("#rTpe").val(result[0][3]);
    $("#rFor").val(result[0][4]);
    $("#shortDesc").val(result[0][5]);
    $("#remark").val(result[0][8]);
  }else{
    alert("Not Found");
  }
}


function updateRequest(){

  if($("#requestNumber").val()!=""){
     $("#updateBtn").attr("disabled",true);
     var updateJson = {};
     updateJson["Short Description"]=$("#shortDesc").val();
     updateJson["Remark Note"]=$("#remark").val();
     updateJson["Assgined To"]=$("#remark").val();
     updateJson["Assgined To"]=$("#assignedTo").val();
     updateJson["Request Status"]=$("#status").val();
     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function (){
         alert("Updated");
         $("#updateBtn").attr("disabled",false);
         }
     ).updateRequestComments($("#requestNumber").val(),updateJson);
  }
}

</script>
```

**Google script:**

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('index')
      .evaluate();
}

function fetchRequestDetails(id){
    var sheetDatabase = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1jrq4fgQdk1ccHGRD3cEY4EQsx5FvXRJuZp-9smOEVsw").getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var columnValues = sheetDatabase.getRange(2, 1, sheetDatabase.getLastRow()-1).getValues(); 
    var searchResult = columnValues.findIndex(id);

    if(searchResult != -1)
    {
      var aData=sheetDatabase.getRange(searchResult+2, 1, 1,sheetDatabase.getLastColumn()).getValues();
      aData[0][1]= Utilities.formatDate(aData[0][1], "GMT +1","yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a")
      return aData;
    }
    return -1;
}

function updateRequestComments(reqID, comments){
    var scriptLock = LockService.getScriptLock();
    scriptLock.waitLock(3000);
      var sheetDatabase = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1jrq4fgQdk1ccHGRD3cEY4EQsx5FvXRJuZp-9smOEVsw").getSheetByName("Sheet1");
      var columnValues = sheetDatabase.getRange(2, 1, sheetDatabase.getLastRow()-1).getValues(); 
      var searchResult = columnValues.findIndex(reqID);
      if(searchResult != -1)
      {
        sheetDatabase.getRange(searchResult+2, 6, 1,1).setValue(comments["Short Description"]);
        sheetDatabase.getRange(searchResult+2, 9, 1,1).setValue(comments["Remark Note"]);
        sheetDatabase.getRange(searchResult+2, 7, 1,1).setValue(comments["Assgined To"]);
        sheetDatabase.getRange(searchResult+2, 8, 1,1).setValue(comments["Request Status"]);
      }
    scriptLock.releaseLock();
}

Array.prototype.findIndex = function(search){
  if(search == "") return false;
  for (var i=0; i<this.length; i++)
    if (this[i].toString().indexOf(search) > -1 ) return i;
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Ritz...You are Great 

I am trying to update Assgined To and Request Status but not able to pull please review  
updateJson["Assgined To"]=$("#assignedTo").val();
updateJson["Request Status"]=$("#status").val();