# Write to a Google Sheet From A Button On Website

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets

Specifically I need to write to a google sheet where the first column is a check box, and it needs to check off when a person clicks on a finish button on my site. Like a list going down and finishing each one. Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use google Sheet as an database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45386321/how-to-use-google-sheet-as-an-database)

Comment: First of all, welcome to StackOverflow! Does this help (specifically the part about embedding a sheet): https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Comment: Google also has a really nice API for using google sheets on your own website: Once you've gone through the setup, you'd be able to do this: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values